# IOS: Polling for every 2 sec

Tags: ios, polling

One feature of my application is to retrieve live data (JSON object) every 2 sec and display it (only while app is in foreground). I can't use push notification service because of server limitations.
Could you please tell me effective way for polling in IOS?

Comment: APNS, or a notification service of some sort is the way you want to be doing this, polling for new data every two seconds will be quite expensive in terms of battery life.

Comment: You might as well poll for new data all the time. The antennas will never have enough downtime to shut down. The battery drain is going to be really bad.

Comment: Btw, "you might as well ..." was meant to say "this is just as bad as doing ..." and should not be considered a validation of polling data.

Answer (score 6):

Polling the network wastes battery, but one option may be a recurrent timer:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self 
   selector:@selector(checkServer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Where you hit the network in your `checkServer:` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer.

```
    poolingTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:pollingPeriod target:self selector:@selector(timerRanOut:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And then in your timerRanOut method you can ask for the new json, parse it, and reload the views.